# Logger Name in Maven2 MOJO

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

From my observation, the logger name assigned to plugin seems to be auto-determined by maven, which is somthing like removing -maven- or -maven-plugin in the artifact name.

Is there any way that I can declare the logger name my plugin will use? Because my plugin artifact id was something like

foo-bar-maven-hello-world

And the resulting logger name become

foo-barhello-world

(which still works, but looks really bad... :P )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can tweak the logger name that gets injected by Plexus (at least, I don't know how to do this).

As an side note, I'd suggest to use the `${prefix}-maven-plugin` or `maven-${prefix}-plugin` pattern for your plugin `artifactid`, this will make the invocation easier without having to set a plugin prefix explicitly.

#### See also

- [Guide to Developing Java Plugins](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html)
- [Retrieving the Mojo Logger](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/common-bugs.html#Retrieving_the_Mojo_Logger)
- [11.4.3. Configuring a Plugin Prefix](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugin-prefix.html)
- [11.4.4. Logging from a Plugin](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-logging.html)

Comment: unfortunately I have read the links you provided before :)
and because the plugins are already in use before I figure out this issue, it is hard for me to change its name already...